# Why would anti-symmetric (0,2) tensor be traceless?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensors

As it is, why would anti-symmetric (0,2) tensor be traceless? Is it because trace should allow any variable for its indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_{ij}$ be (the entries of) a totally antisymmetric tensor. Then, its trace is
$$g^{j i} A_{i j} = g^{i j} A_{i j} = -g^{i j} A_{j i} = - g^{j i} A_{i j} = 0$$
because $g^{i j}$ is (the entries of) a totally symmetric tensor.